# Expand all Bootstrap-Vue b-table rows

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I have a `b-table` which looks something like this:

```
<b-table :fields="fields" :items="tableRows">
  <template #head(expand_all+)="data">
    //would like to make this a button to expand all row-details
    <div class="text-right">{{data.label}}</div>
  </template>
  ...
  <template #cell(expand_all+)="data">
    <div class="expand-arrow-container":class="{ 'expanded': data.detailsShowing }" @click="data.toggleDetails">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="chevron-right" />
    </div>
  </template>
  ...
  <template #row-details="row">
    //display data here
  </template>
</b-table>
```

Now, all of this works fine and and my row details expand/contract as I would expect (see [b-table row-details](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#row-details-support) for more information).

The problem arises in that I want to be able to click one button and expand/contract all the row-details.  My plan is to change `template #head(expand_all+)="data"` into a button which can be clicked to accomplish this. However, I do not know how to do this.  I have searched and read the b-table documentation and have not found any way of accomplishing what I want.  I've even taken a look at the table object to see if it had any references to its rows and I didn't see anything.

Do any of you know a way to accomplish this?  Getting a reference to the rows would make this a simple problem, but as I mentioned I didn't see anything.  I am also not looking to swap out the `b-table` with a bunch of `b-collapse` elements since I have put a lot of work into the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described on the docs, you can set a `_showDetails` property on your items passed to the table. Which if set to `true` will expand that row's details. This means you could loop through all your items and set that property to `true` to expand all rows. And do the same with `false` to collapse them.

> If the record has its `_showDetails` property set to `true`, and a row-details scoped slot exists, a new row will be shown just below the item, with the rendered contents of the row-details scoped slot.

Here's two example methods you could use.
We're using `$set` because we're adding a new property to an already existing object. You can read more about why [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

```js
expandAll() {
  for(const item of this.tableRows) {
    this.$set(item, '_showDetails', true)
  }
},
collapseAll() {
  for(const item of this.tableRows) {
    this.$set(item, '_showDetails', false)
  }
}
```